# SSIS Full Resultset contains no records - Used in Foreach Loop

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I'm building an SSIS package that does dynamic lookups.
First step is that it goes into a table and pulls various records in order to know how to build the dynamic lookup. I pull the results as a Full Resultset because there can be multiple values
Second step is a ForEach loop that runs the dynamic lookup.

In the ForEach Loop, I map variables for the the dynamic lookup.
The dynamic lookup runs in a Data Flow Task. The OLE DB Source uses the variables set in the ForEach loop, so I need to give them default values, otherwise the DB Source doesn't know what to use for an output.
There's where the problem occurs. Because there are times that the ForEach loop should not run at all, because there are no dynamic lookups.
However, because of the default values, it always runs once and sends me the results for the default values.

I have an idea or two on how to get around this, but none of them are clean. I was wondering if there were any best practices for this issue that anyone uses.
Thanks!

Comment: how about a where clause to filter the rows that should not be processed?

Comment: Change setting for that box requiring dataset to DelayValidation (or something similar).